Problem with Rc<RefCell> when using Trees
I wanted to solve the Children Sum Property Problem using Rust (make the tree so that left + right = node). However I keep running into the Borrow Checker.
The problem is part of a DSA course I am trying in Rust
The functions used are (add_left and add_right to add nodes) defined as
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct Node {
    value: i32,
    left: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node>>>,
    right: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node>>>,
}
    pub fn add_left(&mut self, value: i32) {
        self.left = Node::new(value).into();
    }
    pub fn add_right(&mut self, value: i32) {
        self.right = Node::new(value).into();
    }

This was my attempt
pub fn children_sum_property(node: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node>>>) {
    if let Some(node) = node {
        let mut child_sum = 0;
        if let Some(left) = &node.borrow().left {
            child_sum += left.borrow().value;
        }
        if let Some(right) = &node.borrow().right {
            child_sum += right.borrow().value;
        }

        let mut val = node.borrow_mut();
        if child_sum >= val.value {
            val.value = child_sum;
        } else {
            let val_value = val.value; // Store val.value in a temporary variable
            if let Some(left) = val.left.as_mut() {
                left.borrow_mut().value = val_value; // Use the temporary variable here
            }
            if let Some(right) = val.right.as_mut() {
                right.borrow_mut().value = val_value; // And here
            }
        }

        children_sum_property(val.left.clone());
        children_sum_property(val.right.clone());

        let mut total = 0;
        if let Some(left) = &node.borrow().left {
            total += left.borrow().value;
        }
        if let Some(right) = &node.borrow().right {
            total += right.borrow().value;
        }

        if node.borrow().left.is_some() || node.borrow().right.is_some() {
            node.borrow_mut().value = total;
        }
    }
}


However, it gives me an error
error[E0596]: cannot borrow data in dereference of `Ref<'_, binary_tress::Node>` as mutable
   --> src/binary_tress.rs:413:33
    |
413 |             if let Some(left) = node.borrow().left.as_mut() {
    |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
    |
    = help: trait `DerefMut` is required to modify through a dereference, but it is not implemented for `Ref<'_, binary_tress::Node>`

My test case is
let mut root = Node::new(10);
root.add_left(5);
root.add_right(3);
children_sum_property(root.into());


Please add definitions of all non-standard types and functions like Node, Node::add_left, or remove them to complete your [mre]

The code in your error is not in the code you provided and in fact your code does not produce any errors: Playground

Rc<RefCell> is a very bad type for tree without parent pointers.

@cafce25. The code does give an error on runtime (because of RefCell), the error does not appear on compiling.

@ChayimFriedman I do not have a lot of experience in Rust but this is what I am stuck with. I am solving some LeetCode questions with this definition.

I suggest you don't attempt LeetCode questions until after you've learned how Rust works, they are a terrible resource to learn Rust as they commonly use a unidiomatic, if not straight out bad interface.

@KillerFC then what's the relevance of the compiler error in the question? It does not  even match the code in the question? Also then please add a [mre] the code in your question runs without any error besides still some undefined symbols.

The error occurs when we run the children_sum_property on root
let mut root = Node::new(10);
root.add_left(5);
root.add_right(3);
This is what I meant. Sorry if it. wasn't clear from the question

@KillerFC then that call to children_sum_property should be part of the code you show.

The problem is that you mutably borrow node here:
let mut val = node.borrow_mut();

and later borrow it again here:
if let Some(left) = &node.borrow().left {
    total += left.borrow().value;
}

The first borrow is still valid at this point, because val is still in scope, and you can't have two borrows of the same value at the same time unless they are both immutable.
You can easily fix this by explicitly ending the borrow stored in val before making the second borrow, because you don't need val again after that point:
core::mem::drop(val);

if let Some(left) = &node.borrow().left {
    total += left.borrow().value;
}

(core::mem::drop() and std::mem::drop() are equivalent; I tend to prefer the core version because it works on more platforms, but most Rust programs can't run on #[no_std] platforms anyway, and I think std is probably a bit more idiomatic, so you might want to prefer that one.)
As a side note, this sort of singly-linked tree probably doesn't need the power of Rc<RefCell<…>>, because each node does have only one owner (its parent) – you could just use Option<Box<Node>> instead. That would be more efficient, but more importantly, it would give much better error messages (and would catch this particular problem at compile time rather than runtime).

drop is part of the core prleude since at least edition 2015 so you can simply write drop(val).

Thank you! But as I said, Rc is what I am stuck with. Also, could you please help with the last portion of the code, the tree should be 20, 10 (L), 10 (R), but it just changes to 10, 10, 10.

@KillerFC: please ask only one question per question – if you have followup questions it'll be better to ask them in a new post, because most people won't be looking at the comments of answers on random posts, and this site works via people coming across questions they think they can solve and solving them (rather than individual people being assigned to individual questions).

Sure! Thanks you and what if I found an answer to my question should I edit the question to include the answer and the follow up question?

@KillerFC: If you find an answer to your question, you can post it as an answer (you can answer your own question). Follow-up questions should go in a different question. The main idea is that questions should be useful for other people – if someone has the same question as your original question, they should be able to see useful answers to it.
